Meaning of 「口をきゅっと結ぶ」
So I've been reading the 薬屋の独り言 ranobe and came across this sentence: 「猫猫は口をきゅっと結ぶ。」
I can't quite figure out what it expresses in the context: either her unwillingness to talk, or the fear to do so. If possible, I would appreciate you give an appropriate english translation as well.
The broader context:

こいつ以外に目的の奴が見つかるかどうかはわからない。だから、どんな奴かわからないにしても、こいつにかけるしかない。
男が目の前を通り過ぎそうになったとき、猫猫は立ち上がった。
「お、おまえ」
「……」
猫猫は口をきゅっと結ぶ。
男は曲刀を猫猫の首に当てる。
（落ち着け、落ち着け）
猫猫は血がたらりと流れるのを気にする間もなく、口を開ける。

Thanks in advance!

口を結ぶ (or 口を閉ざす) is a set phrase that means to stop oneself from saying something. One possible English translation, according to ChatGPT, is "to seal one's mouth". ギュッと is a mimetic/onomatopoeic adverb expressing the tightness of shutting. In this context, the sentence means she was about to scream in fear but tried to endure it.
